# In Vim block-mode how do I most efficiently select a column?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have a text file that has something like:

```
1   aa    1234
2   bbbb  5678
3   cc    9abc
```

If I put my cursor on the first 'a' in the string 'aa' and hit ctrl-v to enter block mode, is there a set of key-strokes that will move my cursor down to the last line in the same column and move my cursor to the right so that the longest word in the column is fully selected ('bbbb' in this case)?

What I currently do is enter column mode on the first 'a' in the string 'aa' and then down arrow 2, and then right arrow 4.  This seems really inefficient and I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Also, the last line in my example might not be the last in my file.  I could have something like:

```
1   aa    1234
2   bbbb  5678
3   cc    9abc

4   dd    1234
5   eeeee 5678
6   ff    9abc
```

For this question, I'm only interested in selecting the entire column in rows 1-3.

Comment: it'd be a good question for vimgolf ;-)

Comment: @zmo : I didn't know about vimgolf.  That's for mentioning it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [textobj-word-column.vim](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim). It provides text objects for columns. For your example, you'd just position the cursor anywhere in the middle column and do `vic`.

Answer (score 2):

Selection is often not necessary in Vim. Even defining an area to work on, actually.

Vim, unlike spreadsheet programs, only knows about character cell-based columns; not "logical" columns. If your ragged column is not at the end of the line you simply won't be able to visually select it.

But your goal is *not* to select that column, is it?

Do you want to remove it?

```
:,+2norm dw
```

Do you want to append a semicolon?

```
:,+2norm ea;
```

Do you want to surround it with double quotes? Surround.vim to the rescue:

```
:,+2norm ysiw"
```

Do you want to cut it and paste it somewhere else?

```
:,+2 norm "Wdw
```

And so on.

Comment: Actually, I do want to select the column and then either copy, delete, or modify the selection.  At this point I do prefer to use visual-block mode since it gives me visual confirmation that I'm operating on the data that I want to be operating on.  Thanks for your suggestion though.  I wasn't familiar with this approach but I do see how it can be useful.

Comment: Unless the ragged column is at the end of the line you can't have a non-rectangular visual block selection so you simply can't use visual block to achieve your goal without either cutting out a few characters or selecting parts of the second column or unnecessary whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to select based on the longest on the first column, but here's how I'd take out the full column, spaces included:

```
ggfa    ; get to line 1, first column of the table

C-v}k   ; select all the wanted lines as a block selection

$Bh     ; unselect last block

x       ; take out selection
```

and in case you worry about that, you can always realign your columns using the [`Tabular.vim`](http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do after you selected your target column. But it could be done in this way:

```
faWh<c-v>jB
```

if your cursor is already on the first `a`, just

```
Wh<c-v>jB
```

the idea is, move cursor(`*`) to `1 aa   *1234` then enter block-wise selection mode, select the target column backwards.